# Disable USB mass storage via group policy based on the time of day?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, usb, usb-flash-drive

I would like to disable USB mass storage for a group of users during specific hours of the day (lets say, 9AM to 5PM). I know that with Windows Server 2008, there is a group policy that will disable USB storage at:

```
\User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access
```

But, is there a way I can make this policy time dependent?

Perhaps It would be useful to mention that the client machines are running a mixture of Windows XP and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer... no.  Even if you automated the manipulation of the GPO, you couldn't guarantee what time the clients would refresh their policy.

Comment: Could I force a policy refresh using Task Scheduler on the client machines? I was also thinking about using Task Scheduler server-side to enable/disable the group policy. Do you see any issues with this idea?

Comment: Thinking about this more, the setting that needs adjusting is in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, i.e.: in the Computer part of the GPO.  This will need a system restart to take effect.  Doing a brief Google, it might be easier to have a client-side script that does a "sc config usbstore start= disabled" and "sc config usbstor stop".  Just an idea.

Comment: Scratch that.  Just re-read your original Q, and the setting you're manipulating is HKCU.  A scripted GPUPDATE could therefore work.  How many clients are going to hit your DCs though at the same time?

Comment: Around 20 users would be the maximum.

Comment: No real impact then.